# AWS ECS - Cluster Utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecs

According to aws doc, ECS Cluster CPU is calculated as follows.
Cluster CPU utilization =  (Total CPU units used by tasks in cluster) x 100 / (Total CPU units registered by container instances in cluster)
[ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html ]

There are currently four container instances connected to one ECS Cluster.
The Registered CPU for the container instance is 8192(8vCPU). At this time, is the CPU calculation formula correct?
Cluster CPU utilization = Total CPU units used by tasks in four cotainer instances x 100 / 8192 x 4

please answer about my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are cpu reservation and utilization, don't confuse with both things. you'r reserving 32vcpu for 4 containers, for example assume there are 64vcpu with 4 conatiner instances  in entire cluster and if each container is utilizing 4vcpu then you cluster cpu utilization will be 25%

Here is calculation 
4 conatainers utilizing each 4vcpu = 16 
total cluster cpus= 64  then 64/16=25%